# Xdebug not working

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using PHP 5.3.24 on windows 8.1, and I can't get Xdebug to work. var_dump() is not beautified and no error messages are displayed.
The Xdebug module is loading (php -i and php -m both report the module as loaded, and it show up correctly in phpinfo() ), and I've got html_errors = On in php.ini

This is what I have in php.ini:

```
[XDEBUG]
; location of my configuration-file
zend_extension="php_xdebug-2.2.6-5.3-vc9-nts.dll"
xdebug.default_enable = on 
html_errors = on
```

I've tried removing the quotes from arround the zend_extension filename; I've tried different .dll's (I know the thread-safe version is wrong, that doesn't work, likewise the 64 bit version); I've checked the permissions on the .dll itself, I've tried just about everything I can think of!

It looks like the dll is loading but not working properly, does anyone know if there is a specific issue with Windows 8.1 and Xdebug - I've had no problems with Xdebug on Windows XP before now. Or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Saying var_dump() is not beautified, suggests that you're editing the php.ini of your PHP cli instalation but you want in your PHP CGI instalation (for web apps)
Create a php script with phpinfo() in it and run it in the browser. 
Look for :

- Loaded Configuration File
- XDebug entries

Then use this [wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) to verify instalation

Answer (score 0):

Main thing to look for correct configuration of xdebug is in phpize; i.e. the version of phpize should be equal to the php version (version of phpize = php = php-config)

To Display all the php versions installed on your system, use

```
sudo update-alternatives --list php
```

The answer given below is for linux based systems; but in windows you had to use the same concept. i.e. use cmd (run as administrator) instead of shell. e.g. for restarting apache etc.

First set the php to the desired version

To set PHP 7.0 as the default, run

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

To set PHP 7.2 as the default, run

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

To set PHP 7.3 as the default, run

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

To set PHP 7.4 as the default, run

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

Also configure php-config and phpize to the desired version; using similar command

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.0
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.0

sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.2

sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.3
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.3

sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.4

sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize8.0
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config8.0
```

Before we can configure Apache to use PHP (7.2, 8.0 etc, i would use as example 7.2 but any installed version number could be used instead), we need to disable the new (or old) version of PHP by typing

```
a2dismod php7.4
```

Now enable the newly installed PHP 7.2 version with the following command:

```
a2enmod php7.2
```

or
a2enmod php8.0

Restart the Apache web server for the changes to take effect:

For linux

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Rest is same as given on xdebug installation page. i.e.

1. create a php file e.g. info.php in localhost directory . i.e. /var/www/html
2. type in this file
3. Run the file in browser i.e.
   http://localhost/info.php
4. copy all using ctrl + A of info.php file.
5. paste in textarea of

   https://xdebug.org/wizard

follow the steps as directed by xdebug

FYI: remember to use port 9003 instead of port 9000 for xdebug 3
of course for xdebug 2 use port 9000.